# How to split a string containing a numeric value into three parts in PostgreSQL?

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I want to split a given string which could possibly contain a numeric value, using `regexp_matches()`. It should identify the first occurrence of a numeric value containing an optional sign and optional decimal places. The non matching parts should be returned as well - as first and last positions of the array.

Some example input and expected output values:

```
'hello+111123.454545world' -> {hello,+111123.454545,world}
'he-lo+111123.454545world' -> {he-lo,+111123.454545,world}
'hel123.5lo+111123.454545world' -> {hel,123.5,lo+111123.454545world}
'hello+111123.454545world' -> {hello,+111123.454545,world}
'hello+111123.454545world' -> {hello,+111123.454545,world}
'1111.15' -> {"",1111.15,""}
'-.234' -> {"",-.234,""}
'hello-.234' -> {hello,-.234,""}
```

I'm having trouble with the first part of the match group in the following expression represented by 'TODO'. It is supposed to match anything that cannot be identified as a numeric value.

```
select regexp_matches('input', '(TODO)((?:\+|-)?(?:\d*(?:(?:\.)?\d+)))(.*)')
```

The match group represented by '(TODO)' needs to be the negation of the regular expression in the second match group. (As the result is required to be returned). The regex for matching the numeric value works fine, and what I need is how to match the first part of the string which is not a numeric value.

Comment: There is a bug! If you change the first group to non-greedy the 3rd group becomes non-greedy too, which is wrong (and the reason why you might need anchors)! If this is really a postgres issue and not just SQL fiddle it should be reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regexp_matches(input, '(^.*?)([+-]?\d*\.?\d+)(.*$)') AS result_arr
```

- 1st match: `(^.*?)`
  Anchored to the start of the string with `^`. The [*non-greedy* quantifier `*?`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE) is crucial.
  It actually doesn't have to `be the negation of the regular expression in the second match group` because the rest of the regular expression is *greedy*. So the first part is what *remains*, defined by the rest.
- 2nd match: `([+-]?\d*?\.?\d+)`
  I simplified your expression somewhat. In particular a character class `[+-]` is shorter and faster than two branches in non-capturing parentheses `(?:\+|-)`.
  [Non-capturing parentheses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE) are important. (You already had that.)
  <sub>Simplified `\d*` after comment from @maraca.</sub>
- 3rd match: `(.*$)`
  Anchored to the end of the string with `$`. For the last match, make the quantifier *greedy*.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2123) with extended test case.

Comment: (?:\d+)? is the same as \d* and anchoring is not necessary, the difference between my 2nd regex and this one is that it doesn't match a dot in the end, e.g. abc12.def mine will give (abc, 12., def) yours (abc, 12, .def)

Comment: @maraca: `^` is not essential but it can improve performance (`$` is required here). The main difference between your answer and mine is that mine works correctly as opposed to yours: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2125 Valid numbers don't have a trailing dot. That's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: well in this case it is the same as my first regex with a ? after the dot, why is $ required? regex are greedy.

Comment: @maraca: I only saw your answer after your comment. I had skipped all answers with hardly an explanation. Your expressions are similar to mine - except for crucial details which make both your variants fail. I did realize one more simplification that doesn't change the result, though: I changed `(?:\d+)?`  -> `\d*`. Auditing your expressions is too much for a comment. Start another question if you are interested in details. [Here is another fiddle to play with that demonstrates results (including "no row") more clearly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f0f14/2).

Comment: I give the two variants covering all, I expected he can add the `?` himself if he needs it, because in all his examples there is a `.`! And like I said for the `\d*`in the first comment `^` and `$` aren't needed either... it is the same. You know I already had people just copying my answer as update to theirs getting all the upvotes and me none... I don't say you did it here, but you will just end up with the same, I always reference each answer and person that contributed to mine.

Comment: Thank you Erwin. This is perfect. I didn't pay much attention to the start and end of string matching.

Comment: @maraca: Both your expressions are incorrect, for multiple reasons. Look at the fiddles I provided if you can't be bothered to test yourself. I did not copy anything. The good idea I took from your comment is duly credited.

Comment: Actually I tested my regex, but this engine is wrong, it's behaviour is like `...(.*?)` and not like `...(.*)`... multiple reasons?

Comment: ok forget it... just one thing 2nd match the 2nd ? is not needed, as on top.

Comment: Verified again, has to be a **bug** on SQL fiddle, regex are always greedy (unless specified othewise). Maybe it's even a bug in postgresql. e.g. on regex101 it works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex will give you what you want:
`/'(.*?)([+\-]?[0-9\.]+)(.*?)'/g`

Example at: https://regex101.com/r/nF5qV7/1

Comment: fails for abc1.1.1def

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(.*?)((?:\+|-)?(?:\d*(?:(?:\.)?\d+)))(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct regex, assuming there has to be at least one digit after the dot:

```
(.*?)([+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)(.*)
```

Or with optional dot, matches 1. , .7 , +.8, -4 , 0.0 , 42 , ...

```
(.*?)([+-]?(?:\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*))(.*)
```